# Would inductor energy reduce to zero in this case?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I would like to ask about this example. Initially switch at position `a` and then when current reaches some constant value then it's switched to `b`.
I'm interested in what happen in real life.
Someone said that when you switch from a to b, there is a time when the switch is open/floating (R is infinity) so the current is reduced to zero before the switch touch `b`.

Do you agree with this? For what condition the ideal model (no loss in inductor energy when switch switch from a to b) is valid?

[image]

Comment: R is never infinity - but it's not *linear* either. At some point, the potential difference across the coil (L\*di/dt) reaches a value where an *arc* is created. The physics are summarized in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc). [Tony's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/612592/187550) is correct.

Comment: You should use a "make before break" switch if you want to do this experiment in the real world.

Comment: Make before break...but put a fuse in line with the battery (in the name of science...we want to show it is possible)

Comment: Don't forget that even with a relay things are not as clear as you might think: when it switches off, the resistance does not simply jump to GOhm, there is a transition depending on the distance, the humidity, the amount of dirt/rust/etc. Not lastly, there is the breakdown field intensity of air to consider, which is strongly nonlinear (and depends on the voltage). Similarly when it closes in to make contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When switch goes from a to b with open circuit inductor voltage goes towards infinity until the switch arcs.

This means the energy stored in the inductor is transferred into an arc energy unless switched very fast.

V=Ldi/dt and dI/dt is infinite for dry contacts if you ignore switch capacitance. (_ pF)

If switch moves instantly then it might look like this with  T=R/L [s]

[image]

Real-world simulation of 5V logic with RL load at 100 kHz
[image]

- since 5V logic is about 50 ohms +/-50% using 10 load gives different results and exceeds rated current but is closer to ideal switch and demonstrates T=R/L time constant.

[image]

Comment: I think I didn't explain it clear enough. With the ideal model, the switch is assumed to move instantly from a to b in zero time. So no inductor's energy loss. However, in real life, there is some delay, so at what condition the ideal model is still valid (10% error or something similar)?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to solve for the ideal case though. I'm interested in the real life situation instead as I don't have real approximation for off-switch  resistance, capacitance, etc.

Comment: in real life switches are never instant and take about 10 ms moreover if a SPDT switch was instant, then it would create an impulse short circuit. in real life this is common with complementary transistor switches, so delays are used to avoid this called "deadtime" by using fast off, slow ON

Comment: In a real switch it would take time to transfer from one contact to the other but also a real inductor would have self-capacitance so the voltage would not be infinite and it would not discharge in zero time or rise to infinite voltage. Also in practical circuits there would be a diode to catch the voltage so it never rises to infinity and is effectively the same as if the switch transfer instantly.

Comment: You could also use a make before break switch.

Comment: @relayman357  "make-before-break would cause short circuit

Comment: This final examples proves how logic IC overheats from switch 10 ohm inductive load  with 50 ohm RdsOn https://tinyurl.com/y93vo5br

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yikes!  Wasn’t paying close attention.  Agree!